# Blurry/jagged text on iOS

Tags: ios, uikit

I have a UITableViewCell subclass which has a few labels. All of those labels show up with blurry or jagged text. It is much more noticeable on a device than the simulator.

Here's a normal looking label:

[image: good label]

And here's a bad looking label:

[image: bad label]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the issue is due to setting `layer.shouldRasterize = YES` on the UITableViewCell but not setting `layer.rasterizationScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];`.

Or just don't set `shouldRasterize`. I was setting it for performance reasons but these days devices are fast enough you may be fine without it. As always, test for performance issues before prematurely optimizing.